# Visual Studio 2008 Pro does not open DMP files. What could be wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, memory-dump

Microsoft documentation on Visual Studio states, that in order to open dump file, you need to do "File -> Open -> Project" routine.

However, for some reason, in my case VS 2008 does not see dump files - there is no Dump files (.dmp; .mdmp) option in the files filter. Dmp extension is not associated with VS 2008 either.

What could be wrong?

OS: Windows 7 64bit
VS 2008 SP1 Professional.
Dump has been created in 64bit machine.

PS: I've googled all web, but was not able to find a lot on the problem. Apparently, not many people encounter it.

Comment: Did you install a FULL version of Visual Studio Professional?
What happens if you force open the dmp file?

Comment: I did install a Pro version, but apparently *.dmp support was linked to the "C++" support, which I don't use at all. After adding all the C++ options, DMP support has magically shown up.

Comment: I did install a Pro version, but apparently *.dmp support was linked to the "C++" support, which I don't use at all. After adding all the C++ options, DMP support has magically shown up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved.**

After installing C++ support for Visual Studio 2008 I was able to open a dump file for .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to load it using the [64bit NTSD tool](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/install64bit.mspx#)?  Command line is:

```
c:\> ntsd /z dumpfile.dmp
```

If you're not able to load it that way, its probably corrupt in some way.